# How to add Entity Model containing a list of another Entity Model type to Database with EF using lambda expressions and linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2, entity-model

I've got an Entity Model containing a list that is type of another Entity model, I need to add a record with a list of the other model to the Database at once
a null reference exception occurs when I'm adding each prop to prop list with ForEach

```
        public IActionResult RegisterUnitConfirm(InventoryItemUnitViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                InventoryItemUnit unit = new InventoryItemUnit()
                {
                    Title = model.Title,
                    Item_Id = model.Item_Id,
                };
                model.Props.ForEach(x => unit.Props.Add(new InventoryItemUnitProp()
                {
                    Name = x.Name,
                    Value = x.Value,
                    Category_Id = x.Category_Id,
                }));
                DB.Add(unit);
                if (DB.SaveChanges() != 0)
                {
                    TempData["GlobalSuccess"] = "";
                    return RedirectToAction("UnitSummery");
                }
                TempData["GlobalError"] = "";
                return RedirectToAction("UnitSummery");
            }
            TempData["GlobalError"] = "Model State is invalid";
            return RedirectToAction("UnitSummery");
        }
```

Comment: At which line are you getting the null reference exception? Also, have you tried stepping through with a debugger and inspecting the contents of model?

Comment: The exception occurs on line 9,I tried debugging and the contents of the model are not null

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that the error occurs here: `model.Props.ForEach(x => unit.Props.Add(new InventoryItemUnitProp()` and that model.Props is null? Could you show us an excerpt of your model? Also, if you are using a form to submit to this action, could you please show us that as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create new Props when create new unit

like this :

```
InventoryItemUnit unit = new InventoryItemUnit()
                {
                    Title = model.Title,
                    Item_Id = model.Item_Id,
```

> ```
>                   Props=new List<Props>()
> ```

```
                };
```

I hope it will be useful

Comment: Initializing the Props attribute fixed my issue, thanks for your help.